# Typeorm migration generate command including some fields again in each migration while the previous migration generated that field

Tags: node.js, typeorm

```
@Column({ nullable: true, default: null })
baseCurrency: string;   

@Column({ nullable: true, default: null })
description: string;
```

I am having an entity in which above fields are defined , these fields are included in migration .

after generating the migration I am running `typeorm migration:run`  so as per documentation , when i will run generate again then there should be nothing because i didn't change anything but in new migration these two deilds are there .

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 1):

Im facing the same issue with

- typeorm 0.2.32
- mysql 2.18.1

So far I have found that both `nullable: true` and `default: true` cause the problem.

What helped was trying the rc version of typeorm

```
npm install typeorm@0.3.0-rc.21
```